# Ubuntu 12.04 does not recognize graphics card and is completely unresponsive from after the first booting

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB alongside Windows 8 in a Toshiba Satellite L855-149, which has a 2GB dedicated AMD Radeon HD 7670M graphics card.

After I boot and select Ubuntu my screen becomes split and full of stripes. I cannot upload a photo because I have less than 10 reputation. Although I can move the cursor all over the desktop, the system is completely unresponsive to clicking and to commands like **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**T**, even in recovery mode.

I think the problem is that the graphics card has not been properly detected, and that I need to install the appropriate driver manually. But I can't do it because I cannot even open the terminal or anything whatsoever when the Ubuntu desktop has been launched.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this? Also could anybody explain why I do not have this problem while I am running Ubuntu from the flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you fixed it, but people should know there's an easier way.  I had to use it repeatedly when I was trying to use the Unity desktop.

From the desktop you can get to the console, which is a Unix-terminal like text environment.  The console will make you log in with both user name and password.

```
Use the Ctrl-Alt-F1 shortcut keys to switch to the first console. You will be asked on the console to log in with both your user name and your password.

To switch back to Desktop mode, use the Ctrl-Alt-F7 shortcut keys.  And when I just tried it to verify the information I didn't have to log back into the desktop.
```

but I think when you update your driver you might have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Luis Alvarado](https://askubuntu.com/users/7035/luis-alvarado) to the error ["The system is running in low-graphics mode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) fixed this problem for me.

Basically, you have to start terminal in **failsafeX** (wthin **recovery mode**) with  **CTRL+ALT+F1**, enter your user name and password and then install the AMD driver with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

And voila, the graphics card is working!